# How to save button State into SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want create content application, i load data from **JSON** and when users click on `button` save this content into **`SQLitedatabase`**.
I want use [this library](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton) for button.
And for checkable button, I use [this](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sackcentury/shinebutton/MainActivity.java#L69-L74) code

I write below codes, when click on button i save this content into `SQLitedatabase`, but i can't save button sate into **`SharedPreferences`**!

When click on button ([boolean checked](https://github.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sackcentury/shinebutton/MainActivity.java#L71)) button is **turn on**, and when click again on the button **turn off** this button.
I want when click on button, turn on this button and save in `SharedPreferences` and when go to other `activity` and again back this `activity`, see **turn on** this button **NOT turn off**. when click again this button at that time **turn off** button!

**Activity codes:**

```
private ShineButton postShow_favPost;
private String favData = "FavPrefsList";
private Boolean favState;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.post_show_page);

    bindActivity();

    //Give Data
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        title = bundle.getString("title");
        image = bundle.getString("image");
        content = bundle.getString("content");
        dateTime = bundle.getString("dateTime");
        author = bundle.getString("author");
        category = bundle.getString("category");
        categoryID = bundle.getString("categoryID");
    }

    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

    //// Save Fav state
    final SharedPreferences saveFavPrefs = getSharedPreferences(favData, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveFavPrefs.edit();

    favState = saveFavPrefs.getBoolean("isChecked", false);

    postShow_favPost = (ShineButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.post_FavImage);
    postShow_favPost.init(this);
    postShow_favPost.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {

            if (checked == true) {
                editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
                editor.commit();

                //////////// Database
                favDB = new FavHelper(context);

                long addNewFAV = favDB.insertFAV(title, image, content, dateTime, author, category);

                if (addNewFAV < 0) {
                    TastyToast.makeText(context, "Not save in database", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                } else {
                    TastyToast.makeText(context, "Save in database", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.SUCCESS);
                }

                ////////////////////
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checked False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

How can i fix my issue ?

Comment: try replacing .commit() with .apply() for asynchronous process.

Comment: @Lazai, i use `.apply();` in **if** and **else** code, but not work me :( . and when back to activity, see turn off button :(

Comment: @Lazai, can you help me for below post my friend?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to save the state when you click the button. 
For example :

```
postShow_favPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (postShow_favPost.isChecked()){
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
            editor.apply();
     }
     else{
         editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
         editor.apply();
      }
    }
});
```

Then you have to load it in your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    SharedPreferences saveFavPrefs = getSharedPreferences(favData, MODE_PRIVATE);;
    postShow_favPost.setChecked(saveFavPrefs.getBoolean("isChecked", true));
}
```

Maybe this example will help you.

**EDIT**

Ok let's presume in your `f` function you just finished doing whatever you're doing to your database, after that, set the state as **on** or **off**, let's say you want **on**.

So :

```
public void loadPrefs(SharedPreferences prefs){
    favState = prefs.getBoolean("isChecked",false);
}


public void f(SharedPreferences.Editor editor){
//database stuff
 editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true); // or false
 editor.apply();

 loadPrefs(prefs);
```

> // in here your state will be saved for your button as soon as you
>   finish working with your database, after that in your onResume() you
>   may change that state to false(off) in case you want it `just for that post`

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend, but when use this code show turn on for all of posts :D . but i want when click on this button,and save sqlite at that time turn on on this button just for that post not all posts!

Comment: Can you help me for this? please <3

Comment: Well I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to achieve. Once you save the sate for a button in sharedPrefs, it will check its value whenever you want it to check , in the example you're checking it in onCreate(). Try maybe when you're done using the database , use the editor to save the button state as false, then create a callback to load the preference again (this time as false -> turns the button off).

Comment: can you send me for this code? because i am amateur and really need this tutorial. please my friend. please

Comment: Thanks @Lazai, can you send me your email address or connect way with you?

Comment: @Lazia, are you here?